# Errors while running tests

Tags: spring, maven, jakarta-ee, junit, spring-security

I am trying to run my tests using `mvn clean install`, but these errors stop the process. I tried debugging using JUNIT but nothing shown on the console.
these are the logs :

```java
com.datamint.service.impl.EmailServiceImplDevTest:Error creating bean with name'entityManagerFactory'defined in class path resource
    [orm.xml]:BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor':Cannot resolve reference to bean'org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0'while setting constructor argument;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0':Cannot create inner bean'(inner bean)'of type[org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PrePostAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource]while setting constructor argument with key[0];nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'(inner bean)':Cannot create inner bean'(inner bean)'of type[org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.ExpressionBasedAnnotationAttributeFactory]while setting constructor argument;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'(inner bean)':Cannot resolve reference to bean'expressionHandler'while setting constructor argument;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'expressionHandler'defined in class path resource
    [spring-security.xml]:Cannot resolve reference to bean'permissionEvaluator'while setting bean property'permissionEvaluator';nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'permissionEvaluator'defined in class path resource
    [spring-security.xml]:Cannot resolve reference to bean'aclService'while setting constructor argument;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'aclService'defined in class path resource
    [spring-security.xml]:Cannot resolve reference to bean'lookupStrategy'while setting constructor argument;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'lookupStrategy'defined in class path resource
    [spring-security.xml]:Cannot resolve reference to bean'aclCache'while setting constructor argument;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'aclCache'defined in class path resource
    [spring-security.xml]:Cannot create inner bean'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean#a512c9c'of type[org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean]while setting constructor argument;nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean#a512c9c'defined in class path resource
    [spring-security.xml]:Cannot create inner bean'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean#68394e81'of type[org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean]while setting bean property'cacheManager';nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name'org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean#68394e81'defined in class path resource
    [spring -security.xml]:Invocation of init method failed;nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException:Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM.Please provide unique names for each CacheManager in the config or do one of following:
```

What can be the problem? thanks

Answer (score 3):

The cause of the problem is that with the default settings, you cannot have multiple processes sharing the same EhCache. Taken from [here](http://ehcache.org/documentation/get-started/key-classes-methods#introduction)

> CacheManager supports two creation modes: singleton and instance.
>
> Versions of Ehcache before version 2.5 allowed any number of
>   CacheManagers with the same name (same configuration resource) to
>   exist in a JVM. Therefore, each time new CacheManager(...) was called,
>   a new CacheManager was created without regard to existing
>   CacheManagers. Calling CacheManager.create(...) returned the existing
>   singleton CacheManager with the configured name (if it existed) or
>   created the singleton based on the passed-in configuration.
>
> Ehcache 2.5 and higher does not allow multiple CacheManagers with the
>   same name to exist in the same JVM. CacheManager() constructors
>   creating non-Singleton CacheManagers can violate this rule, causing a
>   NullPointerException. If your code may create multiple CacheManagers
>   of the same name in the same JVM, avoid this error by using the static
>   CacheManager.create() methods, which always return the named (or
>   default unnamed) CacheManager if it already exists in that JVM. If the
>   named (or default unnamed) CacheManager does not exist, the
>   CacheManager.create() methods create it.

One solution that will fix your problem (but will slow down the execution of the tests), is to add `@DirtiesContext` to each of your tests that loads the Spring configuration. That will force Spring to recreate all the beans upon running each test class and you'll be able to sidestep the problem.

A solution I prefer in these cases is to run the tests (that don't test caching) using a different profile, where caching is not configured. That way you don't need `@DirtiesContext` and therefore the execution time of the tests if much better

Comment: Thanks. But what is usually the cause of this?